# The same class name implemented in two areas

Tags: ios, class, parse-platform, frameworks, xcode10

I just updated to Xcode 10 and this error started coming up.

`objc[5123]: Class PFFile is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation (0x11cece590) and /Users/erich/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8C3C176C-90F1-4464-AC03-2A987FDC8A9A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/96DFFB9F-BD2A-4F70-93E4-D7DCEF8A8D21/TourneyMe.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse (0x1044739a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

So from the error it seems like my Parse server backend is conflicting with a framework that apple introduced (photofoundation). 
My question is twofold.

1) Can I be sure that when I call "PFFile" that it will not conflict with apples Framework?

2) How can I silence the error?

Comment: Some else just asked the same question a couple of hours earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506493/objc98370-class-pflogger-and-objc98370-class-pffile

Comment: Yes that is the same error. Seems like not a very indepth question though. Hopefully one of them gets an answer!